# List of 10 random points between -2 and 2 with uniform distribution

Tags: python, random, integer, sample, uniform

How do I make a list of 10 random points between -2 and 2 with a uniform distribution? Python keeps telling me that the range is negative or too small

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
randint = random.uniform((1, 10),10)
print (randint)
```

Comment: I'm confused, your code is not even valid Python. What's wrong with simply `random.uniform(-2, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

`random.uniform` only takes 2 arguments: the lower and upper bounds. So you need to call this 10 times:

```
[random.uniform(-2, 2) for _ in range(10)]
```

You can also use Numpy's version. Here you can specify the number of elements:

```
np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.uniform` takes two parameters, a minimum and a maximum,

So you can use a list comprehension to get 10 random numbers:

```
[random.uniform(-2, 2) for _ in range(10)]
```

And here's an example output:

```
[-1.372898354215351, 0.7685608600440506, -0.6975671872462357, -0.3631270499386905, -0.36208667438256414, 0.2822971553695144, 1.427192211459123, -0.9077597437164586, -0.8081649192178384, -1.6619848742793604]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you want.

```
l = []

for _ in range(10):
    l.append(random.uniform(-2, 2))

print(l)

[1.6348754396814087,
 1.8481047445800565,
 -0.125676526622843,
 -0.7042785180355264,
 1.2117300078323434,
 1.2910590071566834,
 -1.939559252995089,
 1.458643196526031,
 1.83268811338445,
 0.03584910568687105]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do:

```
import random
my_random_numbers = [] # initialize list
for i in range(10): # you need 10 numbers
    my_random_num = random.uniform(-2, 2) # they should be between -2, 2
    print(my_random_num) # make sure numbers meet satisfaction
    my_random_numbers.append(my_random_num) # add to our list
```

Outputs:

```
1.6876915611870968
-0.8178893369346687
0.3262903557811643
0.6888991431631117
-1.9753672418552077
0.463925233718546
-0.44685838294827285
-1.1500656906098317
-0.8825768728082863
-1.0350040728799694
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation when posting a solution.